# More button on a tree view

Tags: python, odoo

So I made a view with a tree view but I can't get the "More" button on the tree, also I can't select any records.

Thought this was by default, how can I get it in my tree view?

Code:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_category_overview_tree">
        <field name="name">xx.category.overview.tree</field>
        <field name="model">xx.category.overview</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Category overview">
                <field name="xx_date_creation"/>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="xx_category"/>
                <field name="xx_week_name"/>
                <field name="xx_attending"/>
                <field name="xx_status"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Could you please add the code of your tree view (xml)?

Comment: @CZoellner Added

Comment: I think you just not given access right to model.

Comment: @VikiChavada I'm logged in as admin, it should not have any access rights. Even so I've already added them and no success

Comment: what is the purpose of More button, actually in tree view action, print buttons will come.

Comment: @ShivaGuntuku I mean the default options that you usually have. Example, go to your quotations, you see a list. Select some invoices and the "More" button or action button appears. My problem is that I can't even select records

Comment: are you created form view for the tree view because if click on tree record it will open form view.if your tree, form view code is corrected then default it will create print and action buttons, your tree view is nothing wrong maybe something wrong in act_window and form view.